# downloading problem Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, downloads

I was downloading Ubuntu 14.04  32 bit installation `.iso` file. It all downloaded but the last  some Kb  is not. Can I burn that much and will it install properly  .

Answer (score 1):

An incompletely downloaded Ubuntu iso file is not guaranteed to install properly. Next time use `wget -c` from the terminal to download the Ubuntu iso. `wget` with the `-c` (continue) option will continue the download automatically from the place where it was interrupted until the download is finished. wget is such a powerful program that it will even continue the download from the same place where it was interrupted, if you restart the download from a different mirror. wget is often a lot faster than a torrent depending on the relative download speeds of the mirror and the torrent.

If you are using Windows, the DownThemAll! add-on for Firefox also has the continue functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You need the whole file of course to do an install

First choice, try again later, could be a server issue.

Better choice is to change the download type, [try the torrent version](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads), should not have this issue with that.

On the same page as above you can also find alternative mirrors, pick one near you and then choose the version you would like.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. If you have downloaded the ISO, you should check the hash if it is completed or not. Its better to use torrent. You can do a thing, download .torrent file and point the file location to the one you downloaded earlier. It will check the file and then complete the missing bytes. Then you can install Ubuntu using that ISO. :)

There are step-by-step instructions for how to continue an interrupted direct download from a torrent at [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/218388/how-can-i-continue-an-incomplete-download/218396#218396). This works with Transmission, the default BitTorrent client in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You will likely encounter problem with corrupted iso image. Simply re-download it.